# Passing props to a component using StackNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getAllUsers} from '../actions'
import {List, ListItem} from 'react-native-elements'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native'


const UserDetail = () => {
  <View>
   <Text>User Detail</Text>
  </View>
}

const Home = ({ navigation }) => (
  <List>
    {typeof users === 'string' && 
     <FlatList
      data={users}
      />
     }
  </List>
)

const Stack = StackNavigator({
   Home: {
    screen: Home
   },
   UserDetail: {
    screen: UserDetail
   }
})

class MainScreen extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ users : this.props.getAllUsers() })
}

render() {

    const users = typeof this.props.decks === 'string' 
          ? Object.values(JSON.parse(this.props.users)) : ''

    return(

        <Stack />
    )
  }
 }


function mapStateToProps(users) {
  return {
    users: users,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAllUsers: () => dispatch(getAllUsers()),
 }    
}

 export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
 )(MainScreen)
```

I have two questions:

1) I want to pass the **users** props from `MainScreen` component to `Home` component and later on also to `UserDetail` component. But I could not see any example on that on [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack) documentation except for `ScreenProps`.

2) If I go to UserDetail and let's say it would be a separate component. And let's say it would call another component. How could it go back to `Home` for example?

I'm using `Redux` by the way also here and there are some who suggest to do it in Redux but still I could not make it work also. I am fairly new to React Native or React for that matter, but I could not find a definitive answer so far on this above questions.

Comment: Where is MainScreen in your navigation hierarchy? Once I know that, then I would be able to suggest some.

Comment: The `MainScreen` component is called from `App` component. And supposedly this `MainScreen` component will show a list of users in `Home` and if the user happens to select one of the list, it will go to `UserDetail` component in the **Stack Navigator**. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: So, MainScreen is one of the children of Home component?

Comment: Um, No. MainScreen is not in the Home component in your code. Where is it?

Comment: In my `App.js` I have this `<View style={styles.content}><MainScreen/></View>`. But in `App.js` I don't use **StackNavigator** as in `MainScreen` component.

Comment: Yeap. You should place your StackNavigator at the root and place MainScreen in the StackNavigator. Then, you would figure out how you would pass the props. Normally, we pass an object like this `navigation.navigate('NEXTSCREEN', OBJECT)`. Then access it on NEXTSCREEN with navigation.state.params.OBJECT.